# How to create a toolbar inside viewpart (Not use plugin.xml)

Tags: swt, toolbar, jface

I Created a ToolItem "Save As" like image above, But it not display at toolbar position. So how to create a toolbar inside viewpart (Not use plugin.xml)

**[IMAGE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax44k.png)**

This is my code Create Toolbar:

```
public void createToolbar(Composite parent) {
        // Create composite Toolbar and set layout
        toolBarComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        toolBarComposite.setLayout(gridLayout);

        gridData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.NONE, true, false);
        toolBarComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);

        // Create Toolbar
        gridData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.NONE, true, false);
        toolBar = new ToolBar(toolBarComposite, SWT.FLAT);
        toolBar.setLayoutData(gridData);

        // Create Item
        item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
        item.setImage(SAVE_IMAGE);
        item.setToolTipText("Save (Ctrl + S)");
        item.setEnabled(true);
        item.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -102212312093090431L;

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank for your advance !

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use contributions on the view site's action bar.

**Example**

```
// Copy-pasted from an existing project, so the code can be made nicer
private void createAdditionalToolbarActions()
{
    getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager().add(new GroupMarker("additions")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager().prependToGroup("additions", new SaveAction()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    getViewSite().getActionBars().updateActionBars();
}
```

The method `getViewSite` is part of `ViewPart`. Call this after the contents of the view have been created.

The `SaveAction` must implement `IAction` or `IContributionItem`. For convenience, just extend the `SaveAction` from `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action` and call methods such as `setImageDescriptor` and `setToolTipText`.

Do all your business login in the `run` override.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, but I want ToolItem break down one row below toolbar, How to do it ?

Comment: @Ace I apologize, but I don't fully understand your question. Can't you just create your toolbar on a side-composite?